# Incorrect citation call-out when citing two pieces with same author and same year with one '\cite' instruction

Tags: citing, natbib, apa-style

What should I do when citing two references together in text from the same author and year? At present, the citation year of the second piece changes into `0`.

Example: `\cite{Brown2018a, Brown2018b}` turns into `Brown(2018a,0)`

No error code shows up, and both `Brown2018a` and `Brown2018b` work fine separately. Also no issue with the formatted references, it's just when those are together. The same problem occurs with my other same author and year citations.  I'm using overleaf with pdfLatex with `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`.

```
mybib.bib
    @misc{Brown2018a,
    author= {Brown, A.}, 
    year= {2018}, 
    title= {Example 1} 
    }

    @misc{Brown2018b, 
    author= {Brown, A.}, 
    year= {2018}, 
    title= {Example 2} 
    }

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
Blaa blaa \cite{Brown2018a, Brown2018b} blaaaa blaa blaaa.
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document
```

This turns out like this in references and in text:

[image: in references]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Also I've tried citing with \cite, \citet and \citep and everytime I get "0" in place of the "2018b"

Comment: Without having access to the version of `apalike.bst` that's in your TeX distribution, it's not possible to diagnose what's wrong. My hunch is that the file `apalike.bst` was modified (or got corrupted?) at some point in the past. All I can suggest for now is that you copy the file `apalike.bst` from `https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base` into the directory where your main tex file is located. Rename this file, say, to `apalike-clean.bst`. Then, change `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apalike-clean}` and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I'm afraid I'm unable to replicate the citation call-out issue you say you're encountering, using only the information you've provided so far. Hence, please edit your posting to clarify in which sense either your LateX code or your BibTeX code differs from the minimal working example shown below. Please also state which TeX distribution, which version of LaTeX -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, something else? -- you use and which versions of the `natbib` citation management package and of the `apalike` bibliography style you employ.

To compile the following code, I used the pdflatex program provided by the current version of MacTeX2018, `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>`, `natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b`, and `apalike 2010/12/08 0.99a`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{Brown2018a,
  author = "Anthony Brown",
  title  = "First",
  year   = 2018,
}
@misc{Brown2018b,
  author = "Anthony Brown",
  title  = "Second",
  year   = 2018,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{Brown2018a,Brown2018b}; \citep{Brown2018a, Brown2018b}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to find out the natbib and apalike versions but I've edited some of my code in